# How do I configure HikariCP in my Spring Boot app in my application.properties files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm trying to set up HikariCP in my Spring Boot (1.2.0.M1) app so I can test using it in place of Tomcat DBCP. I'd like to configure the connection pool in my application.properties file like I was doing with Tomcat, but I can't figure out how I should be doing it. All examples I've found show either JavaConfig style, or using a separate HikariCP properties file. Can someone help me figure out the property names to configure it in application.properties? I'd like to also switch from using the driverClassName approach to the DataSourceClassName approach since it looks cleaner and is recommended. Is this also possible in my application.properties file(s)?

Here's what I had for Tomcat DBCP (just some basic config, not fully flushed out)

```
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-on-return=true
```

And I'm currently using driverClassName and jdbc url to set up the connection:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: 1.2.0.M1

I think I might have figured out how to set the properties to set things like maximumPoolSize for hikariCP. But I have been unable to get the configuration working using the hikariCP recommended way using dataSourceClassName and serverName instead of driverClassName and jdbc url. So I gave up on that part. If someone can figure that part, that'd help

Comment: I'll give 1.2.0.M1 a try later on, and I find out anything I'll post it

Comment: You can't use the dataSourceClassName approach with Spring Boot's auto-configuration of a DataSource as it requires that spring.datasource.url is set. Note that you don't need to specify driverClassName as Boot will infer it from jdbcUrl.

Comment: application.properties: `spring.datasource.hikari.*`, documentation: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: Thanks for updating. Originally, back in 2014, this was how they were specified.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "params.datasource")
public class JpaConfig extends HikariConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
params:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
    username: login
    password: password
    maximumPoolSize: 5
```

---

**UPDATED! Since version Spring Boot 1.3.0** :

1. Just add HikariCP to dependencies
2. Configure application.yml

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:TEST
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: username
    password: password
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 10000
```

---

**UPDATED! Since version Spring Boot 2.0.0** :

The default connection pool has changed from Tomcat to Hikari :)

Comment: I think this is a much better, more portable approach. Cheers!

Comment: This could be used for standard spring configuration as well, but one think is important. Hikari used url of datasource via jdbcUrl, but spring via url.

{
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        // HikariConfig hold JDBC-URL in jdbcUrl property, but spring provides this property as url
        this.setJdbcUrl(url);
    }
}

Comment: Sorry this is a bit late reply, but @Sergey solution should slightly be changed in order to get all properties. To get hikari specific DS properties, you need to set the key as "spring.datasource. dataSourceProperties" instead "spring.datasource.hikari"

Comment: Before, we just needed to see how it is configured by looking at the datasource's documentation, now it got worse, we also now need to know how it is configured when using Spring Boot. I don't really see this automagic configuration is really helping us.

Comment: I just wasted several hours trying to get this to work, but hikari was ignoring my config params in the yml file (max pool size in my case). In case anyone else runs into this: do not forget to indent the parameters under hikari!! The example in this post is correct, but in mine I had my maximum-pool-size lined up under the 'h' of hikari instead of indented 2 spaces...

Answer (score 41):

I came across `HikariCP` and I was amazed by the benchmarks and I wanted to try it instead of my default choice `C3P0` and to my surprise I struggled to get the `configurations` right probably because the configurations differ based on what combination of tech stack you are using.

I have setup `Spring Boot` project with `JPA, Web, Security` starters (Using [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/)) to use `PostgreSQL` as a database with `HikariCP` as connection pooling. 
I have used `Gradle` as build tool and I would like to share what worked for me for the following assumptions:

1. Spring Boot Starter JPA (Web & Security - optional)
2. Gradle build too
3. PostgreSQL running and setup with a database (i.e. schema, user, db)

You need the following `build.gradle` if you are using `Gradle` or equivalent `pom.xml` if you are using maven

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com'
version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')

    // Exclude the tomcat-jdbc since it's used as default for connection pooling
    // This can also be achieved by setting the spring.datasource.type to HikariCP 
    // datasource see application.properties below
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

    // Download HikariCP but, exclude hibernate-core to avoid version conflicts
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.5.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
    }

    // Need this in order to get the HikariCPConnectionProvider
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.2.11.Final') {
        exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
        exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
    }
}
```

There are a bunch of excludes in the above `build.gradle` and that's because

1. First exclude, instructs gradle that exclude the `jdbc-tomcat` connection pool when downloading the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependencies. This can be achieved by setting up the `spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` also but, I don't want an extra dependency if I don't need it
2. Second exclude, instructs gradle to exclude `hibernate-core` when downloading `com.zaxxer` dependency and that's because `hibernate-core` is already downloaded by `Spring Boot` and we don't want to end up with different versions.
3. Third exclude, instructs gradle to exclude `hibernate-core` when downloading `hibernate-hikaricp` module which is needed in order to make HikariCP use `org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider` as connection provider instead of deprecated `com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider`

Once I figured out the `build.gradle` and what to keep and what to not, I was ready to copy/paste a `datasource` configuration into my `application.properties` and expected everything to work with flying colors but, not really and I stumbled upon the following issues

- Spring boot failing to find out database details (i.e. url, driver) hence, not able to setup jpa and hibernate (because I didn't name the property key values right)
- HikariCP falling back to `com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider`
- After instructing Spring to use new connection-provider for when auto-configuring hibernate/jpa then HikariCP failed because it was looking for some `key/value` in the `application.properties` and was complaining about `dataSource, dataSourceClassName, jdbcUrl`. I had to debug into `HikariConfig, HikariConfigurationUtil, HikariCPConnectionProvider` and found out that `HikariCP` could not find the properties from `application.properties` because it was named differently.

Anyway, this is where I had to rely on trial and error and make sure that `HikariCP` is able to pick the properties (i.e. data source that's db details, as well as pooling properties) as well as Sping Boot behave as expected and I ended up with the following `application.properties` file.

```
server.contextPath=/
debug=true

# Spring data source needed for Spring boot to behave
# Pre Spring Boot v2.0.0.M6 without below Spring Boot defaults to tomcat-jdbc connection pool included 
# in spring-boot-starter-jdbc and as compiled dependency under spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedb
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword

# Hikari will use the above plus the following to setup connection pooling
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000

# Without below HikariCP uses deprecated com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
# Surprisingly enough below ConnectionProvider is in hibernate-hikaricp dependency and not hibernate-core
# So you need to pull that dependency but, make sure to exclude it's transitive dependencies or you will end up 
# with different versions of hibernate-core 
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider

# JPA specific configs
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbschema
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false

# Enable logging to verify that HikariCP is used, the second entry is specific to HikariCP
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

As shown above the configurations are divided into categories based on following naming patterns

- **spring.datasource.x** (Spring auto-configure will pick these, so will HikariCP)
- **spring.datasource.hikari.x** (HikariCP picks these to setup the pool, make a note of the camelCase field names)
- **spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class** (Instructs Spring to use new HibernateConnectionProvider)
- **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.x** (Used by Spring to auto-configure JPA, make a note of the field names with underscores)

It's hard to come across a tutorial or post or some resource that shows how the above properties file is used and how the properties should be named. Well, there you have it.

Throwing the above `application.properties` with `build.gradle` (or at least similar) into a Spring Boot JPA project version (1.5.8) should work like a charm and connect to your pre-configured database (i.e. in my case it's PostgreSQL that both `HikariCP & Spring` figure out from the `spring.datasource.url` on which database driver to use).

I did not see the need to create a `DataSource` bean and that's because Spring Boot is capable of doing everything for me just by looking into `application.properties` and that's neat.

The [article](https://www.3riverdev.com/tutorial-spring-hibernate-hikaricp/) in HikariCP's github [wiki](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/HikariCP-Articles) shows how to setup Spring Boot with JPA but, lacks explanation and details.

The above two file is also availble as a public gist https://gist.github.com/rhamedy/b3cb936061cc03acdfe21358b86a5bc6

Comment: I was struggling with this right before you posted. Thank you!

Comment: Raf you have an awesome answer.  I was curious if it would be possible for you to post the changes needed for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 . Struggling with the configuration not being picked up and the Migration Guide isn't updated yet

Comment: Hey Mat, I was using 1.5.8 Release when I shared my solution here. I wanted to give 2.0.0.M6 a quick try but, unfortunately they require you to have a higher version of gradle. 

The only change I can remember in 2.0.0.M6 would be making HikariCP default connection pooling for spring jpa see here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d48c414a647427d4fb586c0f362f52e6f5fa2bd8

Try debugging HikariConfig, HikariConfigurationUtil, HikariCPConnectionProvider to make sure that properties is picked up.

Answer (score 26):

You could simply make use of application.yml/application.properties only. There is no need to explicitly create any `DataSource` Bean

You need to exclude tomcat-jdbc as mentioned by ydemartino

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As you won't create `DataSource` bean, you have to explicitly specify using Hikari through `spring.datasource.type` with value `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` in application.yml / application.properties

```
spring:
    datasource:
        hikari:
            connection-test-query: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
            minimum-idle: 1
            maximum-pool-size: 5
            pool-name: yourPoolName
            auto-commit: false
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
        username: login
        password: password
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

In your application.yml / application.properties, you could configure Hikari specific parameters such as pool size etc in `spring.datasource.hikari.*`

Comment: You do not need to exclude the Tomcat to make this work, adding `spring.datasource.type` is enough.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel You need to do the exclusion. The javadoc of `DataSourceBuilder` says: If Tomcat, HikariCP or Commons DBCP are on the classpath one of them will  be selected (in that order with Tomcat first). My testing confirms this.

Comment: @JanBodnar: `DataSourceConfiguration`, which is used in auto-configuration, has the configurations depending on `spring.datasource.type` if it is set at all. So, I have `tomcat-jdbc` on my classpath, and still use HikariCP as my pool. My testing confirms this. Maybe we are talking about very different Spring Boot versions here.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Interestingly, I've managed to run it OK without the exclusion with Java config only by using DataSourceBuilder.create()...type(com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.class). With configuration in the yaml file, it did not work for me. So there has to be some catch.

Answer (score 21):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE. Hikari is default connection pool and `.hikari` is no longer necessary.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB...
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.poolname=myPool
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB...
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        poolName: myPool
```

And `configuration` does not need to extend `HikariConfig`, and `DataSourceBuilder` can be used as it was before.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="myDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need redundant code for putting property values to variables. You can set properties with a properties file directly.

Put `hikari.properties` file in the classpath.

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
maximumPoolSize=20
username=...
password=...
```

And make a datasource bean like this.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("/hikari.properties");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Can the hikari properties be a .yml file too?

Comment: @BugsOverflow I haven't used it for so long time so I'm not sure but it doesn't seem so https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html

Answer (score 11):

According to the documentation it is changed,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Example :

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useSSL=false'
        username: root
        password: pass
        driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        hikari:
            minIdle: 10
            idle-timeout: 10000
            maximumPoolSize: 30
```

These are the following configuration changes we can do on hikari, please add/update according to your need.

```
autoCommit
connectionTimeout
idleTimeout
maxLifetime
connectionTestQuery
connectionInitSql
validationTimeout
maximumPoolSize
poolName
allowPoolSuspension
readOnly
transactionIsolation
leakDetectionThreshold
```

Answer (score 11):

This will help anyone who wants to configure hikaricp for their application with spring auto configuration. For my project, im using spring boot 2 with hikaricp as the JDBC connection pool and mysql as the database. One thing I didn't see in other answers was the `data-source-properties` which can be used to set various properties that are not available at the `spring.datasource.hikari.*` path. This is equivalent to using the `HikariConfig` class. To configure the datasource and hikaricp connection pool for mysql specific properties I used the spring auto configure annotation and the following properties in the application.yml file.

Place `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on one of your configuration bean files.

**application.yml** file can look like this.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASE?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false'
    username: user_name
    password: password
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
        useLocalSessionState: true
        rewriteBatchedStatements: true
        cacheResultSetMetadata: true
        cacheServerConfiguration: true
        elideSetAutoCommits: true
        maintainTimeStats: false
```

Comment: This reply is valuable for providing a working example with data-source-properties!

Answer (score 9):

This works for my boot application in case it helps. This class tells you what properties the config object is looking for:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-common/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/AbstractHikariConfig.java

I think multiple datasources could be supporting by adding `datasource_whatever` to the property keys in the source config file. Cheers!

```
@Configuration
class DataSourceConfig {

   @Value('${spring.datasource.username}')
   private String user;

   @Value('${spring.datasource.password}')
   private String password;

   @Value('${spring.datasource.url}')
   private String dataSourceUrl;

   @Value('${spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName}')
   private String dataSourceClassName;

   @Value('${spring.datasource.connectionTimeout}')
   private int connectionTimeout;

   @Value('${spring.datasource.maxLifetime}')
   private int maxLifetime;

   @Bean
   public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
      Properties dsProps = [url: dataSourceUrl, user: user, password: password]
      Properties configProps = [
            connectionTestQuery: 'select 1 from dual',
            connectionTimeout: connectionTimeout,
            dataSourceClassName: dataSourceClassName,
            dataSourceProperties: dsProps,
            maxLifetime: maxLifetime
      ]

      // A default max pool size of 10 seems reasonable for now, so no need to configure for now.
      HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(configProps)
      HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc)
      ds
   }
}
```

Comment: It is. It's easily translatable to Java though.

Comment: Yeah I'm realizing now that I need to do this because now I want to configure the Metrics. And the only way I can see to do that is with this JavaConfig to override the autoconfiguration. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the dataSourceClassName approach, here is an example with MySQL.
(Tested with spring boot 1.3 and 1.4)

First you need to exclude tomcat-jdbc from the classpath as it will be picked in favor of hikaricp.

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.datasource.dataSourceProperties.serverName=localhost
spring.datasource.dataSourceProperties.portNumber=3311
spring.datasource.dataSourceProperties.databaseName=mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Then just add

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I created a test project here: https://github.com/ydemartino/spring-boot-hikaricp

Answer (score 8):

you can't use dataSourceClassName approach in application.properties configurations as said by @Andy Wilkinson. if you want to have dataSourceClassName anyway you can use Java Config as:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class DataSourceConfig {

 @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String user;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String dataSourceUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName}")
private String dataSourceClassName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.poolName}")
private String poolName;

@Value("${spring.datasource.connectionTimeout}")
private int connectionTimeout;

@Value("${spring.datasource.maxLifetime}")
private int maxLifetime;

@Value("${spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize}")
private int maximumPoolSize;

@Value("${spring.datasource.minimumIdle}")
private int minimumIdle;

@Value("${spring.datasource.idleTimeout}")
private int idleTimeout;

@Bean
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    Properties dsProps = new Properties();
    dsProps.put("url", dataSourceUrl);
    dsProps.put("user", user);
    dsProps.put("password", password);
    dsProps.put("prepStmtCacheSize",250);
    dsProps.put("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit",2048);
    dsProps.put("cachePrepStmts",Boolean.TRUE);
    dsProps.put("useServerPrepStmts",Boolean.TRUE);

    Properties configProps = new Properties();
       configProps.put("dataSourceClassName", dataSourceClassName);
       configProps.put("poolName",poolName);
       configProps.put("maximumPoolSize",maximumPoolSize);
       configProps.put("minimumIdle",minimumIdle);
       configProps.put("minimumIdle",minimumIdle);
       configProps.put("connectionTimeout", connectionTimeout);
       configProps.put("idleTimeout", idleTimeout);
       configProps.put("dataSourceProperties", dsProps);

   HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(configProps);
   HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc);
   return ds;
   }
  }
```

reason you cannot use dataSourceClassName because it will throw and exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: both driverClassName and dataSourceClassName are specified, one or the other should be used.
```

which mean spring boot infers from spring.datasource.url property the Driver and at the same time setting the dataSourceClassName creates this exception. To make it right your application.properties should look something like this for HikariCP datasource:

```
# hikariCP 
  spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampledb
  spring.datasource.username=root
  spring.datasource.password=
  spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
  spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=5
  spring.datasource.minimumIdle=3
  spring.datasource.maxLifetime=2000000
  spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=30000
  spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
  spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
  spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250
```

Note: Please check if there is any tomcat-jdbc.jar or commons-dbcp.jar in your classpath added most of the times by transitive dependency. If these are present in classpath Spring Boot will configure the Datasource using default connection pool which is tomcat. HikariCP will only be used to create the Datasource if there is no other provider in classpath. there is a fallback sequence from tomcat -> to HikariCP -> to Commons DBCP.

Comment: this was super helpful, although I had to figure out few property names not mentioned here like stringType to configure data source props.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the good news. HikariCP is the default connection pool now with Spring Boot 2.0.0.

[Spring Boot 2.0.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#hikaricp)

> The default database pooling technology in Spring Boot 2.0 has been switched from Tomcat Pool to HikariCP. We’ve found that Hakari offers superior performance, and many of our users prefer it over Tomcat Pool.

Answer (score 6):

So it turns out that almost all the default settings for HikariCP work for me except the number of DB connections. I set that property in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=20
```

And Andy Wilkinson is correct as far as I can tell in that you can't use the dataSourceClassName configuration approach for HikariCP with Spring Boot.

Comment: I've been using HikariCP for some time in different applications, and so far never had any problem. I'm using the HikariConfig approach, where you have all your configuration on a properties file. Works as expected with SpringBoot and SpringCore as well. I'm also configuring the maximumPoolSize.

Comment: It should be `spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size` when you use spring config properties, otherwise `maximumPoolSize` is the HikariCP parameter name.

Answer (score 4):

My SetUp:
 
Spring Boot v1.5.10
Hikari v.3.2.x (for evaluation)

To really understand the configuration of Hikari Data Source, I recommend to disable Spring Boot's Auto-Configuration for Data Source.

Add following to application.properties:-

> spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

This will disable Spring Boot's capability to configure the DataSource on its own.

Now is the chance for you to define your own Custom Configuration to create HikariDataSource bean and populate it with the desired properties.

> **NOTE :::**
>  public class HikariDataSource extends HikariConfig

You need to

1. populate HikariConfig Object using desired Hikari Properties
2. initialize HikariDataSource object with HikariConfig object passed as an argument to constructor.

> I believe in defining my own Custom Configuration class *(
>   @Configuration )* to create the data source on my own and populate
>   it with the data source properties defined in a separate file (than
>   traditional: application.properties)
>   In this manner I can define
>   my own sessionFactory Bean using Hibernate recommended: 
>   "LocalSessionFactoryBean" class and populate it with your Hikari Data Source > and other Hiberante-JPA based properties.

Summary of Spring Boot based Hikari DataSource Properties:-

> spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true
>   spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
>   spring.datasource.hikari.catalog=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=100
>   spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-class-name=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-j-n-d-i=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=
>  
>   spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=50
>   spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-fast=true
>   spring.datasource.hikari.isolate-internal-queries=true
>   spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.login-timeout=60
>   spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=500
>   spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=30
>   spring.datasource.hikari.password=
>  
>   spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.read-only=true
>   spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans=true
>   spring.datasource.hikari.transaction-isolation=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.username=
>   spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=

Comment: spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=500 really horrible and it is not recommended from hikari :) https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing

Comment: That was just a sample configuration with Values :)

Answer (score 4):

The code below can be used for a static datasource initialization.

```java
public class MyDataSource {
    private static final String DB_USERNAME="spring.datasource.username";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD="spring.datasource.password";
    private static final String DB_URL ="spring.datasource.url";
    private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS="spring.datasource.driver-class-name";

    private static Properties properties = null;
    private static HikariDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"));

            dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty(DB_DRIVER_CLASS));

            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getProperty(DB_URL));
            dataSource.setUsername(properties.getProperty(DB_USERNAME));
            dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty(DB_PASSWORD));

            dataSource.setMinimumIdle(100);
            dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(2000);
            dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
            dataSource.setLoginTimeout(3);

        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            ((Throwable) e).printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource(){
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        return getDataSource().getConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Now with HikcariCp as default connection pooling with new version of spring boot.It can be directly done as shown below.

```
@Configuration
public class PurchaseOrderDbConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.sysco.purchaseorder.datasoure")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
com:
  sysco:
    purchaseorder:
      datasoure:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/purchaseorder
        username: root
        password: root123
        idleTimeout: 600000
```

If you will print the value of idle timeout value

```
ApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(ApiBluePrint.class, args);
   HikariDataSource dataSource=(HikariDataSource) context.getBean(DataSource.class);
   System.out.println(dataSource.getIdleTimeout());
```

you will get value as 600000 where as default value is 300000 if you dont define any custom value

Answer (score 2):

With the later spring-boot releases switching to Hikari can be done entirely in configuration. I'm using `1.5.6.RELEASE` and this approach works.

**build.gradle:**

```
compile "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.7.3"
```

**application YAML**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      idleTimeout: 60000
      minimumIdle: 2
      maximumPoolSize: 20
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      poolName: MyPoolName
      connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
```

Change `connectionTestQuery` to suit your underlying DB. That's it, no code required.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing issues and the problem was a **whitespace** at the end of `spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

I am working with

```
HikariCP-4.0.3.jar
spring-boot-2.6.2.jar
spring-core-5.3.14.jar
spring-jdbc-5.3.14.jar
spring-web-5.3.14.jar
thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar
```

Looks like spring-boot 2.x has default support for HikariCP out of the box, which is great news.

I had to put in following configurations for 2 different DS in my resources/application.properties

```
spring.sid1.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:SID1
spring.sid1.datasource.username=<user>
spring.sid1.datasource.password=<password>
spring.sid1.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.sid1.datasource.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.sid1.datasource.poolName=SID1Pool
spring.sid1.datasource.minimumIdle=5
spring.sid1.datasource.maximumPoolSize=10

spring.sid2.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:SID2
spring.sid2.datasource.username=<user2>
spring.sid2.datasource.password=<password2>
spring.sid2.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.sid2.datasource.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.sid2.datasource.poolName=SID2Pool
spring.sid2.datasource.minimumIdle=5
spring.sid2.datasource.maximumPoolSize=10
```

Note: spring.sid2.datasource.hikari.* configuration is not required as it is the default new.