# Integrate Spring Boot with EBean and HikariCP Connection Pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ebean, hikaricp

EBean is a stateless ORM.
http://ebean-orm.github.io/

EBean provides a Spring Boot artifact.
http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/setup/spring#spring-boot
https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm-spring

But in that case EBean directly reads jdbc connection details, as follows.

```
ebean.db.ddl.generate=true
ebean.db.ddl.run=true

datasource.db.username=sa
datasource.db.password=
datasource.db.databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:tests
datasource.db.databaseDriver=org.h2.Driver
```

I want to leverage my existing HikariCP DataSource with Spring Boot and EBean.

How do we do that ?

Comment: Just configure it manually asy ou normally would.

Comment: I did not understand how to integrate HikariCP with EBean. 
I am a newbie. 
Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check working EBean + Spring Boot example here:

https://github.com/bwajtr/java-persistence-frameworks-comparison

In that repository there is SpringBoot configuration here: https://github.com/bwajtr/java-persistence-frameworks-comparison/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clevergang/dbtests/DbTestsApplication.java

In that class you can see how EBean is configured and how DataSource is wired into it -> in fact you can use anything which implements DataSource interface, including HikariCP... So use that EBean configuration from DbTestsApplication and setup HikariCP for SpringBoot (check here how to do it: [How do I configure HikariCP in my Spring Boot app in my application.properties files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f))

Answer (score 0):

I was doing that, can now function correctly.

1.application.properties

```
# hikariCP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=@datasource.db.databaseDriver@
spring.datasource.url=@datasource.db.databaseUrl@
spring.datasource.username=@datasource.db.username@
spring.datasource.password=@datasource.db.password@
spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=60
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=3
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250
```

2. Hikari config

   ```
   @Configuration
   @Component
   class DataSourceConfig {

   @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
   private String user;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
   private String password;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   private String dataSourceUrl;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.poolName}")
   private String poolName;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.connectionTimeout}")
   private int connectionTimeout;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.maxLifetime}")
   private int maxLifetime;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize}")
   private int maximumPoolSize;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.minimumIdle}")
   private int minimumIdle;
   @Value("${spring.datasource.idleTimeout}")
   private int idleTimeout;
   public DataSource primaryDataSource() {

       HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
       config.setPoolName(poolName);
       config.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceUrl);
       config.setUsername(user);
       config.setPassword(password);
       config.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
       config.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
       config.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
       config.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
       config.setMaxLifetime(idleTimeout);
       config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
       config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

       HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
       return ds;
   }
   ```

   }
3. ebean

   ```
    @Component
    public class EbeanFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<EbeanServer>, EnvironmentAware {

   @Autowired
   CurrentUserProv currentUser;


   @Autowired
   DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;


   /**
    * Properties used to configure EbeanServer instance
    * (loaded from spring boot application properties).
    */
   Properties properties = new Properties();

   public EbeanFactoryBean() {
   }

   @Override
   public EbeanServer getObject() throws Exception {

       ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
       config.setName("db");
       config.setCurrentUserProvider(currentUser);
       config.setDataSource(dataSourceConfig.primaryDataSource());
       config.setDefaultServer(true);
       config.setRegister(true);
       return EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getObjectType() {
       return EbeanServer.class;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isSingleton() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {

       loadProperties((AbstractEnvironment) environment);
   }


   /**
    * Load into Properties (from Spring PropertySource implementations).
    */
   private void loadProperties(AbstractEnvironment environment) {

       MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();

       // reverse the order of the property sources
       List<MapPropertySource> props = new ArrayList<>();
       for (PropertySource propertySource : propertySources) {
           if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
               props.add(0, (MapPropertySource) propertySource);
           }
       }
       // merge them into the single Properties
       for (MapPropertySource propertySource : props) {
           properties.putAll(propertySource.getSource());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive on that one please? Why did you chose these actions and such