# How to automatically reconnect a DataSource connection in Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, spring-jdbc

Problem: when my spring application is running, and meanwhile the database server is stopped/restarted, then then db connection is lost and *never* restored.

I tested as follows:

- execute query: OK
- service mysql stop
- execute query: exception:

  Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:

  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
- service mysql start
- execute query: still exception!

Question: how can I tell spring `DataSource` to automatically reconnect after connection has been lost?

This is my configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/tablename?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootpw
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-connect=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I had a misconfiguration. The config above is all that's needed for auto reconnect.

Comment: kindly add full prop for `auto reconnect`

Comment: @membersound. Uh no, it isn't it keeps the connection alive, but if a network outage happens it still does not reconnect.

Comment: @dlamblin so what is missing for auto reconnect?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a connection pool like  [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to do a reconnect automatically.

see the example at Stackoverflow: [How do I configure HikariCP in my Spring Boot app in my application.properties files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f)