# Cannot cast SQLServerDriver to DataSource

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

On my Spring Cloud Task project I'm using Spring Batch. I want to separate the metadata (`BATCH_` and `TASK_` tables) from the production data, so I configure two DataSource like this:

```
# DataSource: Production data
prod.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=PROD
prod.datasource.data-source-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
prod.datasource.username=...
prod.datasource.password=...


# DataSource: Jobs and Tasks metadata
tasks.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=TASKS
tasks.datasource.data-source-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
tasks.datasource.username=sa
tasks.datasource.password=...
```

+

```
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prod.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceProd() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tasks.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceTasks() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

+

```
@Configuration
@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceTasks") DataSource source) {
        return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(source);
    }


    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("dataSourceTasks") DataSource source) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(source);
    }

    //+jobs, steps...
```

When I run it, I'm getting `Cannot cast com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver to javax.sql.DataSource` from `taskConfigurer` bean. Do I miss something?

Using Spring Boot starter Batch `2.0.0.RELEASE` and Cloud starter Task `2.0.0.M3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
`prod.datasource.driverClassName`

instead of

```
prod.datasource.data-source-class-name
```

Comment: At first I was using `datasource.url` and it was yelling me to use `datasource.jdbc-url` which I found is from `database.hikari` properties. Then I explored these hikari properties and I saw there is `data-source-class-name` so I guessed I should use it to be "syncroned" with hikari properties. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f

Comment: it can't initialize the schema it seems: `Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener';....Could not increment identity;....Invalid object name 'TASK_SEQ'`

Comment: is TASK_SEQ is exist in db

Comment: No, there isn't, any TASK_ table nor BATCH_

Comment: man i have never work around spring batching, by default spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is none means dev are responsible for creating db schema not hibernate

Comment: It's SQLServer issue. I've created a 2nd data base (using default setting from Management Studio) and maybe it miss permissions. If the 2nd DataSource (Jobs) points to Prod data base, then it's ok

Comment: No, I don't know what permissions needs. Btw, spring batch genereates the schema on my 2nd data base, it's only spring task that doesn't do it. Very strange, why Spring Task would need special permissions but Spring Batch no? I've created the DB as 'sa' and gived the DataSource the 'sa' login

Comment: is there any error logs, or what kind of permission message you are getting

Comment: I figured out that Spring Cloud Data Flow server and the TaskConfigurer Datasources must match. Then it works.

Comment: ohh interesting, may be you can write a blog on it

Answer (score 1):

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` does not implement `javax.sql.DataSource` it's just the driver.

Use a class that implements `javax.sql.DataSource` such as `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`.

Or you could even use an alternative `DataSource` such as a pooled `DataSource` like `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`