# How can we create a retry mechanism if there is an error in the spring boot db connection?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-retry

If there is an error in the db connection while using spring boot, what can be done so that the retry mechanism is activated and the db connection is tried several times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring retry connection until datasource is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553352/spring-retry-connection-until-datasource-is-available)

Comment: Spring itself already has a `DatabaseStartupValidator` which delays the startup. I blogged about this hidden gem about 4 years ago -> https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/ . ALthough you don't need to provide a query anymore in the more recent versions as it will use the JDBC4 `isValid` method to validate the connection (if any). The max delay can be configured, the default is 1 minute.