# PSQLException occurred when processing request

Tags: spring, postgresql, grails

I am running a grails project that has an android client. I migrated my grails project from my local postgres db to an online database server. After I run the grails app the response is for the first few minutes. After that I start getting this error. When I rerun the app the error disappears for the first few minutes then recurs. Note that this problem was non existent when I was using the local database. Here is the full stacktrace.

```
2018-07-13 10:01:37.571 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : This connection has been closed.
2018-07-13 10:01:37.586 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : PSQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/ - parameters:
email: fkamau@gmail.com
action: login
password: 1234
This connection has been closed.. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResultViaListCall(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:801)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.singleResult(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:791)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.invokeQuery(AbstractFindByFinder.java:35)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder$1.doInSession(AbstractFindByFinder.java:29)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.doInvokeInternal(AbstractFindByFinder.java:27)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:252)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:390)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:181)
    at eafyaportal.PatientService.login(PatientService.groovy:55)
    at eafyaportal.ApiController.login(ApiController.groovy:43)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:714)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:680)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:422)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds related to the connection pool abandoning connections. Is there a specific connection pooling implementation that you are using? One of the most commonly used is Hikari. It has options to testOnBorrow which should check if a connection is alive before using it.

[How do I configure HikariCP in my Spring Boot app in my application.properties files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f)