# How to migrate spring DataSource tomcat to hikari properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have the following `tomcat` connection pool configuration from `spring-boot-1.x`. As of spring 2 the default is `hikaricp`. How can I migrate the following properties to the hikari pendant? I could not find them:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-age
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-connect
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-return
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-mills

spring.datasource.hikari.*?
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f

Answer (score 0):

You can find all possible properties for HikariCP [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby).
Although some of the properties you define, are nonexistant in Hikari because of a completely different implementation. Some of them are not even needed anymore.