# Spring Boot 2 disable Autocommit Hikari with multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am attempting to turn off auto-commit on Hikari with multiple data sources, but I'm not having any luck. I'm using Spring Boot 2 (2.0.3.RELEASE). Here is my config:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.primary.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spark?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.primary.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.primary.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.primary.max-active=100
spring.datasource.primary.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.primary.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.primary.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.primary.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.primary.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.primary.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.primary.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000


spring.datasource.ucm.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.ucm.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usercentral?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.ucm.username=xxx
spring.datasource.ucm.password=xxx
spring.datasource.ucm.max-active=100
spring.datasource.ucm.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.ucm.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.ucm.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.ucm.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.ucm.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
spring.datasource.ucm.hikari.auto-commit=false  # <- Not working
```

Here's my configuration class where the data sources are setup

```
@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.primary")
public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return primaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.ucm")
public DataSourceProperties ucmDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name="ucmDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.ucm")
public DataSource ucmDataSource() {
    return ucmDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

Here is what is being output when the pool is created:

```
-2018-08-23 15:48:22.845 -DEBUG 21455 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : 1151 : allowPoolSuspension.............false
-2018-08-23 15:48:22.846 -DEBUG 21455 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : 1151 : autoCommit......................true
-2018-08-23 15:48:22.846 -DEBUG 21455 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : 1151 : catalog.........................none
-2018-08-23 15:48:22.846 -DEBUG 21455 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : 1151 : connectionInitSql...............none
```

How do I turn off auto-commit on this connection pool?

Comment: Hikari is the default in Spring Boot 2, so maybe just leave out the ".hikari."? Also, none of the options after "password" will work - Hikari uses different ones as shown on the [Hikari homepage](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079239/3080094).

Comment: That looks like it worked, it's funny because if I use ignoreUnknownFields = false in my configurationProperties, the app fails to start due to "app.datasource.ucm.auto-commit" being unresolved, but if I set ignoreUnknownFields to true, it appears to work with autocommit turned off!  Thanks

Comment: Does autoCommit default to true for Hikari?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is very late but this issue exploded my brain for ~2 days and this post is at the top of google search so I will post here the solution for others.

It's actually quite simple, just that I missed it in the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

long story short make sure that you add `.type(HikariDataSource.class)` before you build your class.

Also if you use jhipster you should also point your config to the hikari part like this `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.other.hikari")`

Answer (score 2):

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, and faced the same problem. Spent hours with related posts showing non-working properties...

Removing `.hikari` worked for me.

```
spring.datasource.ucm.autocommit=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to your problem, configure **default-auto-commit** property as **false**. It should also work.

```
spring.datasource.ucm.default-auto-commit=false
```

[Spring Boot Ref 1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

[default.auto-commit](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Make false default-auto-commit should work.

```
spring.datasource.ucm.default-auto-commit=false
```