# How to disable autocommit Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to disable autocommit, but I'm not lucky. I'm using the Spring Boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=oracle
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

Comment: the question already exist check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989745/spring-boot-2-disable-autocommit-hikari-with-multiple-datasources)

Comment: But it did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreSoares did you try removing `.hikari`?

Comment: yes, but not did not work. I tried too ```spring.datasource.ucm.autocommit=false``` ```spring.datasource.ucm.default-auto-commit=false``` @Dylan

Comment: tks, solve the problem =D

Comment: how did you solve the problem, could you share the correct one please?

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
spring.datasource.auto-commit=false
```

This property (and some more too) were **not** documented.

Please refer below github issue for more **undocumented** properties.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1829

Answer (score -1):

With Spring Boot 3, the connection pool has been changed to HikariCP and the parameter is now : `spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false`