# HikariCP Spring Boot APP making Postgresql connections finished

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot App where I have configurations as in the attached image. I am getting connection error, that no connection available.

Can anyone please help in this regard? Not able to find the clue to this issue.

In my app I am not making any connection manually. Only I am injecting using `@PersistenceContext` annotation `EntityManager` or using Spring Data JPA `Repository`

When injecting using `@PersistenceContext` I am not closing `EntityManager` manually. Should I do that?

[image]

**Update**

This is the error that is coming when try to use psql to connect to the db
`psql: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already`

**SOME MORE THOUGHTS**

**Case 1:** If i have a loop and in each loop there is a db select
Or if I have a multiple threads and I have db queries in them then more connections will be opened for each query?

**Case 2:** But if i use `@Transactional` on controller endpoints then same connection will be used for all in that method stack

Are the above two statements true? Can the first case result in connections not available error?

Comment: Add the textual error to your question. Check at OS level and DB level how many requests are in process at the moment of the error, if possible. max=10 looks a bit low depending on your application type and load.

Comment: I have updated @LuisMuñoz

Comment: Hey, so probably your Hikari it is consuming the max number of connections available in your PSQL database, because it creates a Pool with connections open and ready to use, and you can limit it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f

Comment: This command " SHOW max_connections;" on portgree shows the maximum number of connections allowed

Comment: Ok its 100. My question is whats wrong? pool of 50 means during app is up out of 100 50 will remain occupied?

Comment: So it means if i run two instances of spring app all 100 connections of postgres will be taken

Comment: Yes, that is the idea..each instance consumes the min-pool size +/- .. so you have to config in order to leave something for DBAs to connect using psql cmd as well.

Comment: And you shouldn't inject EntityManager and then close it manually. It is managed by spring-boot and jpa.