# How to set config parameter into data source's connection into spring boot yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, postgresql-9.3

I have a procedure that required config param from session using current_settings("domainid", "123").
that I need to set into session of HikariDataSource but through yml.

I have tried below ways to set into yml but its not working

1. Set into datasource:
   datasource.connectionProperties: domainid=123
2. Set into hikari
   datasource.hikari
   data-source-properties:
   domainid:123
3. Set into datasource tomcat

   datasource.tomcat.connection-properties:domainid=123

I am using spring boot 2.3.5 release versiin. let me know if anyone has idea. thanks in advance

I can't set below set connection property to yml
public class TenantAwareHikariDataSource extends HikariDataSource {

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = super.getConnection();

    try (Statement sql = connection.createStatement()) {
        sql.execute("SET app.current_tenant = '" + ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantName() + "'");
    }

    return connection;
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = super.getConnection(username, password);

    try (Statement sql = connection.createStatement()) {
        sql.execute("SET app.current_tenant = '" + ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantName() + "'");
    }

    return connection;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show what you mean by (session) here.  Some some code of how you are using session, how you are creating a HikariDataSource, etc

Comment: I have defined Hikari datasource into yml only. and autowired datasource

Comment: Is this what you are after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490967/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-in-my-spring-boot-app-in-my-application-properties-f ?