# How to correctly define hikari datasource

Tags: spring, javabeans

I have the following bean definition.

```
@Bean
public DataSource hikariDataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(JDBC_URL);
    hikariConfig.setUsername(USERNAME);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

When I get application context.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("org.example");
```

An exception is being thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariDataSource' defined in org.example.config.Configuration: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'hikariDataSource' threw exception with message: null
```

Is there any idea what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the answers from this thread will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213802/3816621

Also please check if you get `@Configuration` annotation on class level.

Comment: The annotation is present. Also I have debugged and exception is being thrown after    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig(); line. So I'm able to reach this line.

Comment: If you configure Hikari by the book it could be also a problem with conflicting dependencies.