# Spring4 Hibernate configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I just started learning spring. Actually I am trying to configure hibernate. It is really hard for me, I found a lot of things that I don't understand yet, so sorry If I ask stupid questions.

I copied DataAccessConfig based on this question, 
[Configuration HikariCP + Spring4 + Hibernate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958750/configuration-hikaricp-spring4-hibernate)
but I got an error, here is my example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DataAccessConfig {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    //private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_H_CONNECTION_PROVIDER = "hibernate.connection.provider_class";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.smartintranet.model");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
/*        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_H_CONNECTION_PROVIDER,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_H_CONNECTION_PROVIDER));*/
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SharedEntityManagerBean sharedEntityManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        SharedEntityManagerBean sharedEntityManagerBean = new SharedEntityManagerBean();
        sharedEntityManagerBean.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return new SharedEntityManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.class));

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }
}
```

And tomcat error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/smartintranet/configuration/DataAccessConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1618)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at com.smartintranet.configuration.DataAccessConfig.entityManagerFactory(DataAccessConfig.java:77)
    at com.smartintranet.configuration.DataAccessConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78c2f955.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$2(<generated>)
    at com.smartintranet.configuration.DataAccessConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78c2f955$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$30bdb581.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.smartintranet.configuration.DataAccessConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78c2f955.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processSecondPassesOfType(Configuration.java:1472)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1420)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load Class [org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:491)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:57)
    ... 81 more
```

I will be very thankful for help.

---------- EDIT ---------------------

I did not show my model Entity, here it is. I used wrong type "import java.time.LocalDate;" insted of "import org.joda.time.LocalDate;"

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;



@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate joiningDate;

    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=8, fraction=2)
    @Column(name = "SALARY", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal salary;

    @Column(name = "SSN", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String ssn;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public void setJoiningDate(LocalDate joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((ssn == null) ? 0 : ssn.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (ssn == null) {
            if (other.ssn != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ssn.equals(other.ssn))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", joiningDate="
                + joiningDate + ", salary=" + salary + ", ssn=" + ssn + "]";
    }
}
```

Thx for help [@Master Mind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4726477/master-mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Joda's DateTime class in your Models but whitout specifying the mapping type for it.

import in your build file the following depedency to your project:

```
org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core
```

and this to your code

```
entityManagerFactory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
```